# CSS inheritance, aliases and other cool stuff

Tags: css, inheritance, alias

The other day I was randomly browsing the web and I found some program that lets you write CSS aliases and other cool stuff (which I can't remember right now).

As an example, I remember you can do something like this:

```
.myclass
{
   background-color: red;
   greenfont
}
```

where greenfont was defined somewhere else as somekind of alias

```
greenfont { color: green; }
```

Then the program will generate the resulting CSS based on the alias and other stuff.

Does anyone has used this? Or did I dreamed about it? I cannot find it now :P

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to reply to such an old thread but another one to check out would be LESS
http://lesscss.org

Comment: Yes, LESS is what I'm using right now because it's evolutionary CSS instead of revolutionary (meaning that you don't have to modify your current stylesheets)

Comment: Don't be sorry! This is the sort of thing I was looking for and having more than one answer is much better.

Comment: @emzero, actually SASS now features SCSS, which syntax is compliant with CSS, just like LESS.

Answer (score 0):

Among other similiar projects, there's also http://axr.vg/ for hierarchic styling.